# Handle json error message from REST API through HTTPWebRepsonse

Tags: asp.net, rest, c#-4.0, fiddler, httpwebresponse

I am consuming REST API (provided by client) in C#/asp.net and manipulate json result returned by that REST API. i have consume it by following code.

```
     HttpWebResponse res = null;
     string ReturnBody = string.Empty;

   string requestBody = string.Empty;
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Path);
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentLength = json.Length;

                //Add Basic Auhtentication header
                string authInfo = Username + ":" + Password;
                authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
                request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;

                System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
                sw.Write(json);
                sw.Close();
                res = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                if (res != null)
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), true))
                    {
                        ReturnBody = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
                        s.Append(ReturnBody);
                        sr.Close();
                    }
                }
```

I have put above code in try catch block, so it works properly if it will return success code(200) so i can consume json response from **res** object as per above code

but when that REST API gives error then it will redirect to catch and **res** will be **null** so i can not access json response of error message as i can get it by **Fiddler** as per shown in below fig.

[image: REST test through fiddler]

so help me about **How can i consume that json error response through my code?**

Thanks in Advance! for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be probably getting [WebException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx) - inspect the [status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.status.aspx) property. In your case, it will indicate protocol error i.e. 401/403 etc. In such case [Response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response.aspx) property can be use to get actual HTTP response. For example,

```
try
{
   res = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
   // handle successful response
   ...
}
catch(WebException ex)
{
    if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
    {
       var response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
       // use the response as needed - in your case response.StatusCode would be 403
       // and body will have JSON describing the error.
       ..  
    }
    else
    {
       // handle other errors, perhaps re-throw
       throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what i was looking for, only one question is that when it will go to else{thow;} (some examples)? so i can properly handle it in original catch(exception ex).

Comment: @ArunRana, refer `WebExceptionStatus` value - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus.aspx. For example, DNS failure, request time-out etc would take you to else part.